# KeyPressed calling JInternalFrame returns NullException

Tags: java, keyevent, jinternalframe

I have a JInternalFrame and i want to call another JInternalFrame when i press F1 in a JTextField, however i'm getting NullPointerException. This is my code

GUI:

```
jLabel2.setText("ID:");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
    jLabel2.setBounds(10, 240, 15, 25);
    getContentPane().add(jTextField11);
    jTextField11.setBounds(30, 240, 70, 25);
    jTextField11.addKeyListener(this);
```

KeyEvent:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if( arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F1 ){
        listProducto.setVisible(true);******ERROR******
        Main.getInstance().getPortada().getDesktop().add(listProducto);
        Main.getInstance().getPortada().getDesktop()
                .moveToFront(listProducto);
        try {
            listProducto.setSelected(true);
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `listProducto` is `null` and add the full StackTrace

Comment: Just checked it was a problem with the initialize of the searchForm.

Comment: @LukasKnuth if i already find the solution what can i do? close the question??.

Comment: Answer it yourself and explain what the error was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i forgot to initialize the searchForm in the initComponents();

This is the code that i was missing.

```
listProducto = new ListProducto();
    listProducto.addSearchEventListener(new searchEventListener() {
        public void resultFound(EventObject e) {
            listProductoSearchPerformed();
        }
    });
```

For my searchs i created a searchForm to handle the searchListeners. I add the code of it too.

```
package com.mbpe.search;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import com.mbpe.gui.Portada;
import com.mbpe.main.Main;
import com.mbpe.main.searchEvent;
import com.mbpe.main.searchEventListener;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class searchForm extends JInternalFrame {
public searchForm(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable,
        boolean maximizable, boolean iconifiable) {
    super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable, iconifiable);
}

private List _listeners = new ArrayList();
public synchronized void addSearchEventListener(searchEventListener listener) {
    _listeners.add(listener);
}
public synchronized void removeSearchEventListener(searchEventListener listener) {
    _listeners.remove(listener);
}
public synchronized void fireEvent() {
    searchEvent event = new searchEvent(this);
    Iterator i = _listeners.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ((searchEventListener) i.next()).resultFound(event);
    }
}

public void onClose() {

}

public void onClosing() {
    dispose();
}
```

}